# Postgresql add column on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

I write an sql script in which I want to integrate the creation of a future field depending on the year but i'm not shure if i do it the right way :

```
Do$$
Begin
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(now())>'2025' AND YEAR(now())<'2030'--- 2025-2030
            THEN
            ALTER TABLE public.joinhydro
            ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS
            per_2025 type INTEGER;
        WHEN YEAR(now())>'2030'AND YEAR(now())<'2035' ------------------------- 2030-2035
            THEN
            ALTER TABLE public.joinhydro
            ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS
            turbi_2530 type INTEGER; 
    END;
END
```

Comment: What happens when you run the script more than once for the same time period?  Seems like an odd design.  why not just have a "year" field in the table?

Comment: like I add directly the two fields and I add a condition to populate them afterwards (it would be much easier ^^)

Comment: There is no  `year()` function in Postgres, you need to use `extract(year from current_date)`

Comment: haha my bad, i'm working with qgis at the same time (pseudo sql ) that's why ^^